# Monitor connected via eDP goes black for 1-2 seconds whenever I call xrandr

Tags: xorg, xrandr, displayport, display-rotation

On my hardware there is only one single monitor attached at eDP-1.
And whenever I call `xrandr --query` the monitor turns black for 1-2 seconds, although the command completes without an error.
Also, I did not see any relevant error messages elsewhere. (`syslog`, `dmesg`, `~/.xsession-errors`).
The effect is not just a flicker, but a complete outage.

My theory is that either monitor firmware or something on the main board side crashes and takes the mentioned 1-2s for restarting.
I do not think that there is a general problem with resolution/timings, as the monitor image is stable without calling `xrandr`.

If you wonder why I need to call `xrandr` more often:
I wrote a service that may rotate and dim the display on external data.
And to know if the image is in the right orientation and brightness, I regulary query its current state.
I need all that for an application of mine.

I'm able to provoke the error when running this script.
The screen turns black all the time until I stop the script.

```bsh
while true
do
    echo -n "."
    xrandr --query >/dev/null
done
```

I already tried different combinations to get the location of the error

- Same PC, different monitor on eDP-1 => Same problem
- Same PC, different monitor on HDMI => No problem
- Different PC, different monitor on HDMI, same SSD => No Problem
- Trying next (but need to wait for hardware): different PC, same Monitor on eDP-1

I'm on Ubuntu MATE 20.04.03 and xrandr 1.5.9

Any ideas that could help to diagnose the error?
Where could I look for error messages?